# spring-data - connecting to relational Databases

Tags: rdbms, spring-data

Researching Spring-Data - I understand why you would use for NoSQL databases but am struggling why you would use Spring-Data for relational databases over the standard Spring-ORM capabilities (e.g. the JPA support as standard).

Anyone got clear use-cases why you would use the spring-data framework for relational queries?

Thanks,

James.

Answer (score 2):

The JPA Module of the Spring Data project is different from the NOSQL ones as we don't need to provide a low level store abstraction ourselves. So the main features are:

- elimination of a large chunk of the implementation code needed for repositories (see this [blog post](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/10/getting-started-with-spring-data-jpa/) for a showcase)
- abstractions for pagination and dynamic sorting
- DDD specifications to allow defining domain predicates (see this [blog post](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/) as example)
- support for [Querydsl](http://querydsl.com) predicates
- transparent entity auditing

The JDBC module of Spring contains support for Querydsl as well.